# Is a while loop that only yields the best practice for pausing a function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a function that calls a first dialogue box, then needs to wait for the user to press the space bar before it displays the second dialogue box. I can accomplish this easily with a coroutine, by yielding within a while loop as follows:

```
message.PlayMessage();

    while (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) == false) {
        yield return null;
    }

message.PlayMessage(2);
```

My question is: is this a weird solution?  I feel like there might be an actual function for this, and I fear that maybe this is eating up a lot of system resources for no reason.

Comment: I think this is Unity's equivalent of `await`, and it shouldn't use too many resources.

Comment: I think it's good. Because coroutines do not start any new threads. Simply check `Input` every frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'll be called once in a frame, not expensive. 
And making Wait function is more convenient.

```
    IEnumerator MyMethod() {
        message.PlayMessage();
        yield return StartCoroutine(WaitForKeyDown(KeyCode.Space));
        message.PlayMessage(2);
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForKeyDown(KeyCode keyCode)
    {
        while (!Input.GetKeyDown(keyCode))
            yield return null;
    }
```

And call.

```
StartCoroutine(MyMethod());
```